# Is it possible to include pyramid modules in template file(in python code block)?

Tags: python, pyramid, mako

I use .mako file as template and i need get information about current session. How am i supposed to do it? 
My idea: import session factory in python code block in my template file.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: If I understand correctly, try ${request.session} in template

Answer (score 2):

Pass the necessary session information to the template in a variable from the view.

```
@view_config(renderer='foo.mak')
def my_view(request):
    return {'mysession':request.session}
```

Comment: Probably you don`t understand my question. 
I solved this problem by session factory in mako file

Comment: You were asking for an alternative way.

Comment: No, i asked details, not alternative way

Answer (score 0):

Request object is available in MAKO templates context.

You can use it directly in your template.

Example:

```
${request.session}
${request.session.get('SOME_VARIABLE')}
```